# Why would presenting UIImagePickerController overwrite my template image tintColor?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, tintcolor

I am dealing with an issue where merely presenting a `UIImagePickerController` changes the tintColor of every single one of the `[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]` images from white to the global tint color. This occurs after I dismiss the UIImagePickerController, and only applies to `UIImages` that I set on a `UIButton`. It does not seem to apply to `UIImageViews`.

Does anyone know why this might happen? It's like there is some kind of strange layout pass iOS is doing that is wiping out my manually specified tintColors on every UIImage.